# Почему вместо двух потоков создается 3? с#

Tags: c#

Есть программа, которая обращается к базе данных и по получает оттуда информацию. Результат выполнения программы - вывод в журнал логов шины. Должно выводить следующим образом:
"В таблице:0 - 111
В таблице:1 - 222
...
...
...",
где 0 и 1 - это имя потока, а 111 и 222 - получаемые из базы данные.
Потоки создаются в цикле и в эти потоки передаются SQL-запросы по порядку от 0 до 8. Количество потоков зависит от количества запросов в массиве.
В моем случае используется два запроса для обращения к двум таблицам.То есть очевидно, что у меня должен выводиться результат, как я написал в самом начале. Но вместо ожидаемых двух строк в журнале выводится три строки
"В таблице:0 - 111
В таблице:1 - 222
В таблице:0 - 222."

Часть кода, отвечающего за работу привожу ниже.

```
public void Run(IMessageSource messageSource, IMessageReplyHandler replyHandler, CancellationToken ct)
{
    // Выполнение команды 
    RefreshServer r = new RefreshServer(this);
    JArray items = JArray.Parse(_command.Replace("\"", ""));
    int length = items.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        // передаются строки
        r.command = items[i].ToString();
        r.connectString = _connectionString;

        // Создается новый поток с именем, который запускает функцию SQL в классе 
        RefreshServer
        Thread tr = new Thread(r.SQL) // Как основной вариант, более устаревший 
        {
            Name = i.ToString() 
        };
        tr.Start();
                
    }
}
// класс RefreshServer для многопоточности
public class RefreshServer
{
    // получаются строки
    public string command;
    public string connectString;

    // получается ссылка
    private readonly OutgoingConnectionPoint parent_;
    public RefreshServer(OutgoingConnectionPoint parent) => parent_ = parent;

     // функция многопоточности
     public void SQL()
     {
         Thread.Sleep(10);
         OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, con);
         string data = "";
         try
         {
             con.Open();
             parent_.WriteLogString("Соединение для отправки в - (" + connectString + ") проверено");
              Thread.Sleep(5000);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             parent_._logger.Error("Ошибка установки соединения!", ex);
         }
         try
         {
             OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                  data = reader["KEY_ID"].ToString();
                  parent_.WriteLogString("В таблице:" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " - " + data);
             }
             con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             parent_._logger.Error("Ошибка выполнения запроса!", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, с чем могут быть связаны проблемы

Comment: `while (reader.Read())` - значит, в таблице больше одной строки. Сколько строк, столько и выводится `parent_.WriteLogString`.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` - код на помоечку

Comment: В таблицах по одной строке, поэтому и выводится 111 и 222 из первой и второй соответственно. Вопрос про то, что при запуске двух потоков, вместо двух выводимых результатов, получается 3

Comment: _В таблицах по одной строке_ - не верю! (c) Что за БД такая странная, с таблицами по одной строке?

Comment: Что ещё с ходу видно: класс `RefreshServer` не является потокобезопасным. В частности, поле `command` меняется в цикле: `r.command = items[i].ToString();` и используется внутри метода `SQL`: `new OleDbCommand(command,`. Если первая итерация ещё не успела выполниться, то на второй итерации значение изменится.

Comment: Пройдите код в отладке. И такие ошибки сразу выловятся. Делов на несколько минут.